# Making @Singular and @Builder work in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, lombok

I am using lombok plugin in eclipse. 
My class look like:

```
@Builder
@Data
class A{
 @Singular
 private final List<String> products;
}
```

Whenever I change anything in class and save in eclipse. Eclipse is adding  multiple final keyword before class. 
Example:

```
final @Builder
@Data
class A{
```

What is solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got problems with added `final` as well, even without `@Builder`. This happens to me when the code is syntactically invalid. In your code, there's `Class` instead of `class`, which may or may not be related.

Fixing the error often does not help. To circumvent the problem, switch off "Save Actions", fix and save the file. I'm afraid that's all we can do at the moment. The culprit is the "Add final modifier to local variables" action.

I've just filed [an issue](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/882).

Comment: regarding class -> Class. That was just typo.

Answer (score 1):

save actions and lombok are more or less incompatible. We have to choose; either @Getter and @Data and such play nice with eclipse features like cmd/ctrl-clicking a getter so that it jumps to the appropriate annotation, or save actions work.

This issue tracks the problem: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/882

We can fix it, it's just a lot of work, so we probably won't get to it for a while.